# How to get safe area size/padding in Flutter

Tags: flutter, padding, flutter-layout

I'm using a SafeArea Widget and want to extract the height of the bottom area which is not within the safe area. As recommended in other sources I tried using `MediaQuery.of(context).padding` but it always returns `EdgeInsets.zero`. Is there any other way of getting the size of the bottom region which is not within the safe area?

EDIT:

I had SafeArea widget's bottom property set to true (`bottom: true`) which always resulted in `EdgeInsets.zero`. Setting `bottom: false` returns the actual SafeArea's bottom padding value.

Answer (score 58):

To get **Bottom padding** use

```dart
final bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
```

To get **Top padding** use

```dart
final topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
```

If you want to get height of App Bar which is used as flutter Material component

```dart
AppBar appBar = new AppBar();
appBar.preferredSize.height;
```

Comment: This does not give you the dimensions of what a safe area adds

Comment: But it gives ability find it atleast. Any way I guess there is no dedicated method to find so. It will be great if you could tell me any.

Comment: It worked in my case, to get the difference of height in case Safe Area is applied or not, thank you Swapnil.

Answer (score 9):

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window).size;
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window).padding;
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. When I use the SafeArea, using `MediaQuery.of(context).padding` always returns `EdgeInsets.zero`.
Can you explain why is that?

Comment: those exactly what I needed in my case, thanks

the only note here is that they are deprecated, and deprecation message suggests its alternative `MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context)).padding`

Answer (score 7):

To get only Safe Area's height, try to access MediaQuery somewhere before adding SafeArea in the widget tree. This way you will get `MediaQuery.of(context).padding` with some value instead of `EdgeInsets.zero`. Padding is set to zero after insertion of SafeArea in the widget tree.

Doc for the child of SafeArea Widget says

> The padding on the MediaQuery for the child will be suitably adjusted
> to zero out any sides that were avoided by this widget.

So to get height excluding the height of all the system layers, try -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    final heigth = size.height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
    return SafeArea(
        ...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SafeArea widget's bottom ant top properties buy default are set to true.
Setting 'bottom: false' and 'top: false' returns the actual SafeArea's bottom and top padding value.

```
 return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ...
```

Comment: Please provide some code, so the question gets more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.10.0, the window singleton is deprecated( https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton). Therefore, to obtain the safe area padding, you must now apply the following:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

MediaQueryData.fromView(ui.PlatformDispatcher.instance.implicitView!).padding
```